# AWS InvalidParameterValueError - Environment named ... is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be pending deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I did django deployment using AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Loadbalancer Server everything working fine initially

I am getting this error when I am trying to deploy my django app on EC2 using `eb deploy`

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Environment named ... is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be pending deployment.
```

I am not sure about this please help me anyone. Thanks in advance ...